# SQL search using multiple boolean operators

Tags: sql

I am trying write a somewhat complicated sql search. I'm new to SQL and not 100% sure how sql interprets my expression.

I have a table that's like this:

```
| job_name | progression | status |
```

I'm trying to turn this boolean operator into a SQL expression

```
job_name LIKE (software OR SDE) AND NOT LIKE (embedded OR intern OR manager OR test OR SDET) AND progression IS (("Phone screen" AND (Status IS "yes))  OR ("On-site" AND (Status IS "yes" OR "no")))
```

I have something like this

```
select * from jobs
where job_name LIKE '%SDE'
OR job_name LIKE '%software%'
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%embedded%'
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%intern%'
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%manager%'
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%test%'
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%SDET%'
```

This seems to work fine. But when I start adding in the operators to add in `progression` & `status`, things fall apart.

Basically I want to see every row with `job_name` that contains `SDE` or `Software` in it (but not the not like) and that has a stage `Phone Screen` and `Evaluation` equals `Yes` OR a stage `On-site` and `Status` is `Yes` or `No`

I am using SQLite & SQLite studio

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of precedence is probably what's causing an issue here. I can never remember how it works exactly between AND/OR in SQL, and even if I could I wouldn't expect anyone reading my code to remember. Thus, I'd suggest using parentheses to resolve ambiguity. Something like the below should work:

```
select * from jobs
where (job_name LIKE '%SDE' OR job_name LIKE '%software%')
 AND job_name NOT LIKE '%embedded%'
 AND job_name NOT LIKE '%intern%'
 AND job_name NOT LIKE '%manager%'
 AND job_name NOT LIKE '%test%'
 AND job_name NOT LIKE '%SDET%'
 AND (other conditions)
```

Comment: I think the parens around the and are not really helpful personally, but are an absolute must around the Or.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean agree, updated result to make it more readable and intuitive

Answer (score 0):

Try with parenthesis:
select * from jobs
where (job_name LIKE '%SDE'
OR job_name LIKE '%software%')
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%embedded%'
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%intern%'
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%manager%'
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%test%'
AND job_name NOT LIKE '%SDET%'